# How to merge 2 lists from different callbacks?

Tags: java, merge, callback

I have a **callback** that I use in two methods,for getting likes and visits that get data from **Realtime Database**.

```
 public interface ActionCallback {

        void setActionList(List<ActionModel> actionModels);

    }
```

Each of them has callback of ActionCallback type as a method parameter.

```
private void getLikes(ActionCallback callback){
        realtimeReference.child("Likes").child(getUid()).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                List<ActionModel> actionModels = new ArrayList<>();
                for (DataSnapshot snapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    actionModels.add(new ActionModel(
                            Long.valueOf(snapshot.child("timestamp").getValue().toString()),
                            snapshot.getKey(),
                            "likes"));
                }
                callback.setActionList(actionModels);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
        });
    }

    private void getVisits(ActionCallback callback){
        realtimeReference.child("Visits").child(getUid()).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                List<ActionModel> actionModels = new ArrayList<>();
                for (DataSnapshot snapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    Long timestamp = Long.valueOf(snapshot.child("timestamp").getValue().toString());
                    String fromUid = snapshot.child("fromUid").getValue().toString();
                    actionModels.add(new ActionModel(timestamp, fromUid, "visits"));
                }
                callback.setActionList(actionModels);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
        });
    }
```

I need to **merge lists** from their callbacks in getSortedList() method, I try to do like that, but it doesn`t working for me and I receive only getLikes() list.

```
 public void getMergedActions(ActionCallback callback){
        List<ActionModel> actionModels = new ArrayList<>();
        getLikes(actionLikeModels -> {
            actionModels.addAll(actionLikeModels);
            getVisits(actionVisitModels -> actionModels.addAll(actionVisitModels));
            Collections.sort(actionModels, (e1, e2) -> Long.compare(e1.getTimestamp(), e2.getTimestamp()));
            callback.setActionList(actionModels);
        });
    }
```

Comment: You're leaving out a lot of context. Is the callback method `getList()` or `getActionList()`? What's `getLikes()`? What's `getVisits()`? Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Why is the method named `get` if it does a `set` operation, i.e. supplies a parameter with data to give into the method? I could understand `get` if the parameter was a result-collector, but that doesn't seem to be the case here.

Comment: I add all needed code and edit naming. Is it clear now to understand?